# Why does my C++ console shut down when its about to take user input?

Tags: c++

I am going through a PDF tutorial for C++ and currently doing a drill for a simple letter program.  The program takes my input but when it comes to the 2nd input, it just shuts down.  I'm quite new in C++ so excuse my ignorance.  This is my code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string first_name, last_name, dest_firstName, friend_Name;
    char friend_sex = '0';
    int dest_age = 0;

    cout << "Enter your first and Last Names" << endl;
    cin >> first_name;
    cin >> last_name;

    cout << "Hello " << first_name << " " << last_name 
        << ". Enter the name of the person you want to write to. " << endl;
    cin >> dest_firstName;

    cout << "Enter their age" << endl;
    cin >> dest_age;

    cout << "Enter the name of another friend." << endl;
    cin >> friend_Name;

    cout << "Enter the gender of the friend." << endl;
    cin >> friend_sex;

    cout << "Dear " << dest_firstName << ", " <<endl;
    cout << "How are you?  It has been a long time since we spoke.  Have you seen "
        << friend_Name << " lately? "<< endl;
    if (friend_sex == 'm') {
        cout << "If you see " << friend_Name << ", can you ask him to call me?" << endl;
    }
    else if (friend_sex == 'f') {
        cout << "If you see " << friend_Name << ", can you ask her to call me?" << endl;
    }

    else if (dest_age = 0 || dest_age >= 110) {
        cout << "Also, I've heard that not long ago was your birthday and you are "
            << dest_age << " years old.  NO WAY" << endl;
    }
    else if (dest_age < 12) {
        cout << "Also, I've heard that not long ago was your birthday and you are "
            << dest_age << ".  Next year you will be "
            << dest_age + 1 << " years old." << endl;
    }

    else if (dest_age == 17) {
        cout << "Also, I've heard that not long ago was your birthday and you are "
            << dest_age << ".  Next year you will be able to vote. " << endl;
    }

    else if (dest_age == 70) {
        cout << "Also, I've heard that not long ago was your birthday and you are "
            << dest_age << ".  I hope you're enjoying retirement." << endl;
    }

    cout << "Yours Truly" << endl;
    cout << first_name << " " << last_name << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

And this is the output:

`Dear John,

How are you?  It has been a long time since we spoke.  Have you seen  lately?

Also, I've heard that not long ago was your birthday and you are 0.  Next year you will be 1 years old.`

`Yours Truly`

`Onur Ozbek`

Comment: Replace this line ``else if (dest_age = 0 || dest_age >= 110) {`` with ``else if (dest_age == 0 || dest_age >= 110) {``

Comment: If you type in a space in the name input then all the remaining inputs will instantly fail

Comment: Turn warnings on for your compiler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might helps, try adding both `cin.sync();` and `cin.clear();` after asking an input.
Cheers!

Comment: Thank you very much.  I already solved the problem.  If you think that this was a well asked question, can you give me an upvote?

Answer (score 1):

You simply have a typo in that line: `else if (dest_age = 0 || dest_age >= 110)`
it should be `else if (dest_age == 0 || dest_age >= 110)`.

I recommend you to use a debugger next time.

Comment: But the problem remains, "How to properly handle the user input to insure you are dealing with valid input, and not a stream error (e.g. `badbit, failbit, eofbit` and how to handle the error conditions?" Otherwise, the question should simply be closed as a "off-topic typo".